Equation of Time (derivation Analemma)
In the document available here:
http://info.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/mul/mueller.pdf
I have been able so far to reproduce all missing details so far to the relation (33) of page 7:
$$\sin E=\frac{E-M}{e}=\sin M+\frac{e}{2} \sin 2 M+\frac{e^2}{8}(3 \sin 3 M-\sin M)+\ldots$$
However (it must be very likely obvious but i don't get it...) i don't understand how from (33) the author get (34), ie:
$$\sin 2 E=\sin 2 M+e \sin M 2 \cos 2 M+\ldots$$
Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

That's trigonometry:
$$\sin (\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\beta\cos\alpha$$
or simplified with $\alpha = \beta$ to
$$\sin 2\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$$
This identity is applied to the taylor expansion mentioned above in the text, giving the results quoted.
Check out, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities for a list of useful trigonometric identities.

Arrrrrrrrrrrgh That's so obvious now that you say it! I need to take a rest! Thanks a lot
